# Android Studio not showing any errors?

Tags: android, compiler-errors, android-studio

I don't know what happened
but when i copy paste a code or write something
**No Errors were shown**

See the picture below in which i copied a code but no imports yet
But Android studio doesn't show any error.
Even when i `Ctr + Alt + O` It doesn't imports anything
[image]

Is their any setting to get it back or anything else?

I already tried updating all available updates

Comment: move arrow on un-imported class,interface or etc and and use ALT + ENTER.

Comment: I accidentally entered into power saver mode

Comment: I faced this problem just after upgrade to 4.1

Comment: I experience this problem all the time... but restarting android studio it works for me.

Answer (score 29):

Sounds like you may be in power save mode. Check it on the `File` menu, just above `Exit`. While in power save, code inspection is disabled.

To get code inspection running again, you can either: 1) exit power saver mode, or 2) run inspection manually with `Inspect Code...` on the `Analyze` menu.

Comment: File - Essential Highlighting - disable it (if it's enabled)

Answer (score 9):

On the right side, click on the smiling face and pull the progress bar at the right:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 9):

I fix this problem by reset setting: File > Manage IDE Settings > Restore Default Settings.

After reinstall plugins, I realized that `butter knife` plugin was the problem

[image]

[image]

Comment: After uninstall butter knife plugin, my android studio is cured.

Comment: Butter Knife Zelazny was the culprit in my case. fixed it. You saved me.

Answer (score 1):

Clean your Project and press  `ALT + ENTER` for `import` into android studio

Answer (score 1):

in logcat view

try to remove any filter or filter by your application

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click on bottom right corner icon in android studio and uncheck the Power Save Mode

Comment: Second icon from the right, "current inspection profile"

Answer (score 1):

What fixed mine in **Android Studio V. 2022.1.1 Canary 3** was that I had "**none**" selected for the highlighting which showed up as "**OFF**" in the **top-right corner** of the code box:

[image]

Clicking on that popup box that was now there:

[image]

And I noticed it said "**Highlight None**". clicking on that **blue link** gave me 3 options:

[image]

Selecting the "All Problems" brought me to this stats popup box:

[image]

Once that was done doing its thing I was **finally** presented with errors in my code! (which really isn't good but its good in this step-by-step guide):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On the right bottom side, click on the user face and uncheck the power Save Mode.

Answer (score 0):

For me none of the ones above helped.

I found the solution by doing this.

`Analyze` --> `Inspect Code...` --> Check - "`Whole Project`"

*Also if this doesnt work out. Check if one of your classes need to implement some methods and the compiler is not recognizing that.*

*Try also:*

`Code` --> `Implement Methods...`

Answer (score 0):

go to this path  => C:\Users\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\plugins

find =>  Groovy_Console_Plugin_8542.zip

check it is extracted if not then => extract hear

then you will get result

note: check your Highlighting level (inspection level) is on syntax

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `./gradle` folder and then relaunch Android Studio to download/install the Gradle automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Invalidate caches and restart helped me

Answer (score 0):

I found a fairly easy solution, would try this first.

1. Close the project.
2. Open it as a new project: Instead of clicking on the existing project in the typical way, go to File > Open, or click on the Open button in top right corner, if in the "Welcome" dialogue box
3. Give it a few seconds to load the project and run all the related checks, etc.
4. That should do it!

Answer (score -3):

On your right side , theres are colored squares next to the page scroll. Typee on the red square to see the error.

Answer (score -3):

Following worked for me:

While opening a new project, be sure you connect your system with power,

restart and then enable safe mode and when the settings pop up

set the check for compile if not checked.

Good Luck

Comment: Please mention something relevant to the question